# How do I copy a Map?

Tags: javascript

I was surprised to find that the following doesn't create an `m` with size 1:

```
  let a = new Map();
  a[1] = 2;
  let m = new Map(a);
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 3):

The Map is being copied. It just doesn't have any data stored in it.

You need to use the `set` method to assign a value to a Map. Arbitrary properties are not given special meaning.

```
let a = new Map();
a.set(1, 2);
let m = new Map(a);
```

Comment: I think you could underline OP's problem by showing that `a.get(1)` returns `undefined` (while `a[1]` - the object's field `1` - does return 2)

Answer (score 2):

Map is not an array so it acts a bit differently.

To add an item to a map use:

```
map.set('key','value')
```

see more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map